# Is there any way to compile a blade template from a string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I compile a blade template from a string rather than a view file, like the code below:

```
<?php
$string = '<h2>{{ $name }}</h2>';
echo Blade::compile($string, array('name' => 'John Doe')); 
?>
```

http://paste.laravel.com/ujL

Comment: You've written some code that looks good - what's wrong with it?

Comment: I have tried `$string = '<h2>{{ $name }}</h2>';
    echo Blade::compileString($string, array('name' => 'John Doe'));` nothing returned.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556981/render-blade-from-string-instead-of-file/31435824#31435824  Just pointing the link where you would find more solutions

Answer (score 23):

I found the solution by extending BladeCompiler.

```
<?php namespace Laravel\Enhanced;

use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler as LaravelBladeCompiler;

class BladeCompiler extends LaravelBladeCompiler {

    /**
     * Compile blade template with passing arguments.
     *
     * @param string $value HTML-code including blade
     * @param array $args Array of values used in blade
     * @return string
     */
    public function compileWiths($value, array $args = array())
    {
        $generated = parent::compileString($value);

        ob_start() and extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        // We'll include the view contents for parsing within a catcher
        // so we can avoid any WSOD errors. If an exception occurs we
        // will throw it out to the exception handler.
        try
        {
            eval('?>'.$generated);
        }

        // If we caught an exception, we'll silently flush the output
        // buffer so that no partially rendered views get thrown out
        // to the client and confuse the user with junk.
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            ob_get_clean(); throw $e;
        }

        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return $content;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot.
Just to help someone like me I can add to your post that a way to instancing a custom compiler extension is to pass  filesystem instance ad path to compiled views  to the constructor:
 
`$myBlade = new MyBlade(App::make('files'), App::make('path').'/storage/views');`

Comment: How did you get laravel to use this blade compiler?

Answer (score 19):

Small modification to the above script.
You can use this function inside any class without extending the BladeCompiler class.

```
public function bladeCompile($value, array $args = array())
{
    $generated = \Blade::compileString($value);

    ob_start() and extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    // We'll include the view contents for parsing within a catcher
    // so we can avoid any WSOD errors. If an exception occurs we
    // will throw it out to the exception handler.
    try
    {
        eval('?>'.$generated);
    }

    // If we caught an exception, we'll silently flush the output
    // buffer so that no partially rendered views get thrown out
    // to the client and confuse the user with junk.
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        ob_get_clean(); throw $e;
    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This solution works quite good. However, I have noticed an issue with foreach loops.


<ul>
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <li>{{ $item }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

This code does not render and I get this error:
Undefined variable: __env

Is there a solution?

Comment: $mail_template = MailTemplate::where('name',$name)->first();  $this->bladeCompile($mail_template->body,array('price' => 300));

Answer (score 18):

For anyone still interested in this, they've added it to Laravel 9

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
 
return Blade::render('Hello, {{ $name }}', ['name' => 'Julian Bashir']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates

Comment: If you are using Laravel 8.x you can copy the function from 9.x as is and it will work with Laravel 8.x, Tested with php 7.4

The function render() is in [BladeCompiler.php] (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a9bd0ce3b5354fb07861b56263c998819854d5bb/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L282)

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled upon the same requirement! For me, i had to fetch a blade template stored in DB & render it to send email notifications.

I did this in laravel 5.8 by kind-of Extending `\Illuminate\View\View`. So, basically i created the below class & named him StringBlade (I couldn't find a better name atm :/)

```html
<?php

namespace App\Central\Libraries\Blade;

use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class StringBlade implements StringBladeContract
{
    /**
     * @var Filesystem
    */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
    */
    protected $viewer;

    /**
     * StringBlade constructor.
     *
     * @param Filesystem $file
     */
    public function __construct(Filesystem $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->viewer = view();
    }

    /**
     * Get Blade File path.
     *
     * @param $bladeString
     * @return bool|string
     */
    protected function getBlade($bladeString)
    {
        $bladePath = $this->generateBladePath();

        $content = \Blade::compileString($bladeString);

        return $this->file->put($bladePath, $content)
            ? $bladePath
            : false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the rendered HTML.
     *
     * @param $bladeString
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function render($bladeString, $data = [])
    {
        // Put the php version of blade String to *.php temp file & returns the temp file path
        $bladePath = $this->getBlade($bladeString);

        if (!$bladePath) {
            return false;
        }

        // Render the php temp file & return the HTML content
        $content = $this->viewer->file($bladePath, $data)->render();

        // Delete the php temp file.
        $this->file->delete($bladePath);

        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a blade file path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function generateBladePath()
    {
        $cachePath = rtrim(config('cache.stores.file.path'), '/');
        $tempFileName = sha1('string-blade' . microtime());
        $directory = "{$cachePath}/string-blades";

        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            mkdir($directory, 0777);
        }

        return "{$directory}/{$tempFileName}.php";
    }
}
```

As you can already see from the above, below are the steps followed:

1. First converted the blade string to the php equivalent using `\Blade::compileString($bladeString)`.
2. Now we have to store it to a *physical* file. For this storage, the frameworks  cache directory is used - `storage/framework/cache/data/string-blades/`
3. Now we can ask `\Illuminate\View\Factory` native method 'file()' to compile & render this file.
4. Delete the temp file immediately (In my case i didn't need to keep the php equivalent file, Probably same for you too)

And Finally i created a *facade* in a composer auto-loaded file for easy usage like below:

```html
<?php

if (! function_exists('string_blade')) {

    /**
     * Get StringBlade Instance or returns the HTML after rendering the blade string with the given data.
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @param array $data
     * @return StringBladeContract|bool|string
     */
    function string_blade(string $html, $data = [])
    {
        return !empty($html)
            ? app(StringBladeContract::class)->render($html, $data)
            : app(StringBladeContract::class);
    }
}
```

Now i can call it from anywhere like below:

```html
<?php

$html = string_blade('<span>My Name is {{ $name }}</span>', ['name' => 'Nikhil']);

// Outputs HTML
// <span>My Name is Nikhil</span>
```

Hope this helps someone or at-least maybe inspires someone to re-write in a better way.

Cheers!

Comment: Dope dude thanks! StringBlade is sick! its like String Cheese...... kinda.. haha

edit: orrrrrr Sling Blade!?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not using blade this way but I thought that the compile method accepts only a view as argument.

Maybe you're looking for:

```
Blade::compileString()
```

Comment: $string = '<h2>{{ $name }}</h2>';
echo Blade::compileString($string, array('name' => 'John Doe')); "name" is not assign to the template.

Answer (score 4):

It's a old question. But I found a package which makes the job easier.

[Laravel Blade String Compiler](https://packagist.org/packages/wpb/string-blade-compiler) renders the blade templates from the string value. Check the documentation on how to install the package.

Here is an example:

```
$template = '<h1>{{ $name }}</h1>';  // string blade template

return view (['template' => $template], ['name' => 'John Doe']);
```

**Note: The package is now updated to support till Laravel 6.**

Comment: The answers from above will solve the issue without any package.

Comment: Doesn't it throw undefined $name exception? before it reaches view function just wondering

Comment: @sumeet I do not think as `$name` is not a variable, it is just part of string

Answer (score 4):

I know its pretty old thread, but today also requirement is same.

Following is the way I solved this on my Laravel 5.7 (but this will work with any laravel version greater than version 5), I used the knowledge gained from this thread and few other threads to get this working (will leave links to all threads at the end, if this help up-vote those too)

I added this to my helper.php (I used [this technique](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) to add helper to my project, but you can use this function directly as well)

```
if (! function_exists('inline_view')) {
    /**
     * Get the evaluated view contents for the given blade string.
     *
     * @param  string  $view
     * @param  array   $data
     * @param  array   $mergeData
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
     */
    function inline_view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        /* Create a file with name as hash of the passed string */
        $filename = hash('sha1', $view);

        /* Putting it in storage/framework/views so that these files get cleared on `php artisan view:clear*/
        $file_location = storage_path('framework/views/');
        $filepath = storage_path('framework/views/'.$filename.'.blade.php');

        /* Create file only if it doesn't exist */
        if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
            file_put_contents($filepath, $view);
        }
        
        /* Add storage/framework/views as a location from where view files can be picked, used in make function below */
        view()->addLocation($file_location);

        /* call the usual view helper to render the blade file created above */
        return view($filename, $data, $mergeData);
    }
}
```

Usage is exactly same as laravel's `view()` helper, only that now first parameter is the blade string

```
            $view_string = '@if(strlen($name_html)>6)
                                <strong>{{ $name_html }}</strong>
                            @else 
                                {{$name_html}} 
                            @endif';
            return inline_view($view_string)->with('name_html', $user->name);
            return inline_view($view_string, ['name_html' => $user->name]);
```

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31435824/4249775
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33594452/4249775

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 9 :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
 
return Blade::render('Your Blade Content {{ $parameter1}}', ['parameter1' => 'Name']);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as an already given answer.