# Blade :: compileString() and embedded variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am able to parse HTMl that uses blade template variables through the following code:

```
    $generated = Blade::compileString($string);

    ob_start();

    try
    {
        eval($generated);
    }

    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        ob_get_clean(); throw $e;
    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
```

And it works fine as long as i don't use blade variables within. Which on being parsed give me undefined variable error. How can i make sure that blade variables are available in my custom parsing method?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why you run `eval` on `$generated` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek eval runs the `$generated` code and then returns the parsed string. but if the original string contains variables, it says undefined variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anyway around to compile blade template like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-anyway-around-to-compile-blade-template-like-this)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me with the latest version of Laravel 5.7. Notice how I include the __env var so that functions like @include, @foreach, etc can work.

```
public static function renderBlade($string, $data = null)
{

    if (!$data) {
        $data = [];
    }

    $data['__env'] = app(\Illuminate\View\Factory::class);

    $php = Blade::compileString($string);

    $obLevel = ob_get_level();
    ob_start();
    extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);

    try {
        eval('?' . '>' . $php);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        throw $e;
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        throw new FatalThrowableError($e);
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not passing the arguments array to the method that parses the Blade structure. My assumption was that the `Mail::send` method takes care of making variables available which it takes in as a second parameter. I also had to `extract($args, EXTR_SKIP)`.

```
$generated = Blade::compileString($string);

ob_start(); extract($args, EXTR_SKIP)

try
{
    eval($generated);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    ob_get_clean(); throw $e;
}

$content = ob_get_clean();

return $content;
```