# How to Display Blade Content stored in a Db row

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

How can I Effectively Display Blade code stored in a DB instead of being displayed as a line of code?

here is the [image](http://i59.tinypic.com/3dd6u.png)

Inspecting the html I see 
" 
{{HTML::ul(array('a', 'b', 'c'))}}
"
If I can get rid of the quotes the blade content will be displayed

Comment: Are '{{' and '}}' included in your db?

Comment: yes, should it be included? by the way, i dont need some sort of security because it will be only for the admin part. Just like the  graphic shows

Comment: why would you store blade code in a database anyway?

Comment: well yes, I Will use plain HTML, it wasnt like a must, just wanted to see if I could. Txs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile blade syntax string, stored in a DB row or a variable by extending Blade Compiler. 
Solution code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string), I have not tested the code myself.

```
<?php namespace Laravel\Enhanced;

use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler as LaraveBladeCompiler;

class BladeCompiler extends LaraveBladeCompiler {

    /**
     * Compile blade template with passing arguments.
     *
     * @param  [type] $value [description]
     * @param  array  $args  [description]
     * @return [type]        [description]
     */
    public function compileWiths($value, array $args = array())
    {
        $generated = parent::compileString($value);

        ob_start() and extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        // We'll include the view contents for parsing within a catcher
        // so we can avoid any WSOD errors. If an exception occurs we
        // will throw it out to the exception handler.
        try
        {
            eval('?>'.$generated);
        }

        // If we caught an exception, we'll silently flush the output
        // buffer so that no partially rendered views get thrown out
        // to the client and confuse the user with junk.
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            ob_get_clean(); throw $e;
        }

        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return $content;
    }

}
```

Comment: indeed it is a Blade Issue

Comment: Well, as I stated earlier, I Just need HTML code pulled from a DB I will use  plain HTML to code my view, so you have helped me with the solution. Thank you.