# Render html image tag from database in the Laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to store the complete code including:

```
img src="{{ (asset('/img/' .$variable. 'image.jpg')) }}"
```

in the database and display it on the page with Laravel 5.

My problem is that the image `src` attribute is not rendering properly.

I will appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: 1. What's your image name in your database? 
2. What is the content of `$variable`? 
3. What's the path for **img** directory?

Comment: In case I have  src="http://localhost/projects/test/public_html/img/image1.jpg"
It will work, but I need to store a variable instead of "http://localhost/projects/test/public_html" is there is a way I can do it?

Comment: Do you mean like this: src="{{ asset('/img/image1.jpg') }}"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a string which is retrieved from the database: `img src="{{ (asset('/img/' .$variable. 'image.jpg')) }}"`. Not a blade template.

So in order to convert it to a blade template you will need to compile this string to a blade template. Shortly you will need a blade compiler. Laravel has a [`Blade::compileString()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_compileString), try it. If it still didn't work for you, follow the following links, which I am sure will help you.

The most easy solution for you: [This answer for a possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16982287/2169355)

[A related blog post](http://sharpten.com/blog/2014/08/15/explicitly-parsing-blade-code-laravel-4.html)

There are also some libraries for compiling and parsing blade templates:

https://github.com/Flynsarmy/laravel-db-blade-compiler

https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the problem clearly.
I want to save the whole tag in the database like this :
<img src="{{ asset('img/image.jpg') }}">
It is not just an image1.jpg that is stired in the database.

So when I view source on the page, the image src remains src="{{ asset('img/image.jpg') }}" instead of src="https://website/img/image.jpg"

Comment: @nb_ck got you know. Edited my question, check it now.

Comment: Mustafa, Thank You! I will try this out.