# Render view from path Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I'm building a modular system in Laravel 5 and the modules views of my system are outside from the `/resources/views`. They are under `/modules/XXXXModule/core/views`.

When I use the `return view('viewFileHere')` it doesn't work (logically) because is looking for the views in the wrong place.

How can I tell Laravel 5 to search for the views in other place (path)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of adding new paths for views in Laravel:

**1. By using `addLocation`:**

```php
view()->addLocation('/modules/XXXXModule/core/views');
view()->addLocation('/modules/YYYYModule/core/views');
```

The above will work but if you have a `list.blade.php` view in each of the folders, if you use this:

```php
return view('list');
```

it will always return the one it finds in the location registered first, which in this case would be for `XXXXModule`. So while it works it has its drawbacks for your modular structure.

**2. By using `addNamespace`:**

```php
view()->addNamespace('XXXXModule', '/modules/XXXXModule/core/views');
view()->addNamespace('YYYYModule', '/modules/YYYYModule/core/views');
```

The above will register each path in a different namespace, so if you have two view files with the same name (i.e. `list.blade.php`) but are part of two different modules you can access them as following:

```php
// for XXXXModule
return view('XXXXModule::list');

// for YYYYModule
return view('YYYYModule::list');
```

This way you have no more conflicts of location.

Comment: Wonderfull! Thanks you!