# Problems in parsing variable within body stored in database

Tags: laravel-5

I have an issue in parsing variable.

I have dynamic email template for all types of email like registration,activation and so on

Suppose i want to send feedback email and i have email template for feedback  stored in database.

In database it is stored as Name:{{ $name }}

But when i sent email it is sending Name:{{ $name }} instead of actual name like Name:john

Following is my code:

```
 $name = $request->get('name');
            $address = $request->get('address');
            $phone = $request->get('phone');
            $emailaddress = $request->get('email_address');
            $feedbacktext = $request->get`enter code here`('message');


            Mail::send('lugmety.frontend.partials.contactUsEmail',
                [   'name' => $name,

                ],
                function ($mail)
                use ($address, $name,$phone,$emailaddress,$feedbacktext) {
                    $mail->to('anandshrestha57@gmail.com')->subject('FeedBack Form')->from($emailaddress,$name);
                });
```

Here is my view which contains email template obtained from database.

```
<?php echo \App\EmailTemplate::where('slug','contact-us')->first()->body; ?>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: this is not possible in laravel. As we know that laravel render its blade template in .php file than it saves it to `storage\framework\views` folder.  So if you are echo some databse var like `{{ $someData }}` than it is converted into .php file `<?php echo _e($someData) ?>` than the databse valu goes here so it will not work

Comment: So we have to make separate view for every email template . Isnot there any sort of idea to overcome such problem @sunny kashyap

Comment: suppose i save as format {{ name }}, is there any way that {{ name }} can be replaced by actual name while sending email . I mean there must be way .I see pyrocms has such features. - @ sunny kashyap

Comment: i think it is only possible with laravel mutators. Mutators can make changes in database object just before they are accessible. But than you have to find out how you can pass your customers name to that function (because it is dynamic)

Comment: in your case you are accessing name from $request so can you can do this check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
private function parsed_content($email_template, array $args = array()){
    $generated = \Blade::compileString($email_template);
    ob_start() and extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    try{
        eval('?>'.$generated);
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        b_get_clean(); throw $e;
    }
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

And for parsing variable in email template stored in database:

```
 $emailTemplate = EmailTemplate::where('slug','contact-us')->first();

        $email_body = $this->parsed_content($emailTemplate, array(
            'name' => $name,
            'address' => $address,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'emailaddress' => $emailaddress,
            'feedbacktext'=>$feedbacktext
        ));


        $body = json_decode($email_body,true)['body'];
```

And for sending email:

```
 Mail::send([],[],
                function ($mail)
                use ($body,$address, $name,$phone,$emailaddress,$feedbacktext) {
                    $mail->to('anandshrestha57@gmail.com')->subject('FeedBack Form')->from($emailaddress,$name)
                    ->setBody($body,'text/html');
                });
```

So no need of making every view. Source:@[Is there any way to compile a blade template from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)

Comment: check here @sunny kashyap https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in `EmailTemplate` Model

```
//$value is $EmailTemplate->body value
public function getBodyAttribute($value)
{
  //get value name by request function
  $name = request()->get('name');

       //do your regex code to replace {{ name }} from $name in $value and update.....

  //finaly return $value;
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @sunny kashyap .I had figured one solution for this. Actually laravel has blade compile that can render string as blade templates. So when i stored email template in database it parsed the value so we neednot necessary to create view for every template. Below here is the method