# How does @include work in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to write a custom directive in laravel. However, it only returns the path of my blade partial as a string, not the actual html like @include does.

```
@customInclude('authenticated/partials/header2') 


    Blade::directive('customInclude', function($partial){
        if(Config::get('constants.ORG_ID') === 'organizationId'){
            return "<?php echo $partial; ?>";
        }
    });
```

I want the custom directive to return the html found in the path 'authenticated/partials/header2' , however, it seems that blade is not recognizing that the path is a path in my php. My custom directive lives in the AppServiceProvider.php file btw. Does anyone know how @include works really well so they can explain why my path isn't being recognized.

Comment: Hint. `$partial`'s value is `authenticated/partials/header2`. What happens when you `echo authenticated/partials/header2;`?

Comment: @ceejayoz the page bonks out. Returns syntax error, unexpected 'authenticated' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Right, because you've generated `<?php echo authenticated/partials/header2; ?>` in the resulting compiled Blade template. That's not valid PHP, and even if you made it valid by adding the `'`s around it, it would just echo the path to your template file. You need to make your custom directive *do* something.

Comment: @ceejayoz ah darn it. do I need to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string

Comment: You might *possibly* be able to make that work, I guess? `return Blade::compile("@include('$partial')");` *may* get you what you want, even if it's fairly inelegant. I suspect there's a more Laravel way if you dig into how the `@include` directive already works.

Comment: @ceejayoz No cigar. But I am definitely closer. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool question, it took a bit of digging, but you can replicate what laravel does quite easily:

```
Blade::directive('customInclude', function($partial){
    if(Config::get('constants.ORG_ID') === 'organizationId'){
        return "<?php echo view($partial); ?>";
    }
});
```

Comment: I get this error FatalErrorException in ec6488ec73fd89a9fcb067be4180e524 line 0:
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception when trying to implement the above.

Comment: Sounds like your partial might have an error in it? Try a simplified blade to start with - like a foo.blade.php with just "hello world".   Also clear you view cache with php artisan view:clear

Comment: Ah seems you are right. However, the issue is now that the template doesn't recognize variables that it used to when I just did a regular @include. I read up on another post, and incuded echo view($partial)->render(); I now get a Undefined variable error.

Comment: You can call the `view($partial)` method as per the normal view() method you call in your controllers, including passing in data as the second argument. If you want to just pass in everything, call `view($partial, get_defined_vars())`

Comment: Alright, I now get a page isn't working error in Chrome and a connection reset error in Firefox when passing in get_defined_vars(). I believe I have too many variables. When I pass in the specific variable into the view() method, I get the same error that the variable is undefined.

Comment: I saved the get_defined_vars() in a variable as an array but now I get a Array to string conversion

Comment: Edit: I don't believe the get_defined_vars() are being pulled in through the custom directive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris for your answer. It was correct. However, if you want to pass in specific variables to your view. Do the below

```
    Blade::directive('customInclude', function($partial){
        if(Config::get('constants.ORG_ID') === 'organizationId'){
            return "<?php echo view($partial,compact('variable1','variable2','variable3')); ?>";
        }
    });
```

The whole including variables through compact() threw me off.

Comment: No worries. As mentioned in my comment, you just pass the variables as per the normal view method. Compact is not required, but rather its a nifty shortcut.