# How to process string like blade template in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have code :

```
$a = test
$string = 'test {{ $a }}';
```

I want to process string in $string variable as blade template. I know I can save this to temp view something like this:

```
$a = test
$string = 'test {{ $a }}';
file_put_contents('temp.blade.php', $string);
$processedString = View::make('temp', compact($a));
```

but I don't want to save temp file, I want something like :

```
$a = test
$string = 'test {{ $a }}';
$processedString = View::makeFromString($string, compact($a));
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to compile a blade template from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

No, by default laravel does not support this, but this package

```
https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler
```

work like charm for me.