# Variables not rendering when template is passed from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have in database template for email with variables ant etc.. 
When I pass that template in my view from database variable are not rendered and displayed {{ $child_fullname }}, {{ $specialist_fullname }} and etc. instead of given name.

Here is my Mail build function:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Pranešimas apie sėkmingą registraciją')
                ->view('email-template')
                ->with([
                    'body'                => EmailTemplate::find(1)->text,
                    'child_fullname'      => $this->child->name . ' ' . $this->child->surname,
                    'specialist_fullname' => $this->card->specialist->name,
                    'date_time'           => $this->visits->workSchedule->work_date . 
                                             ' ' . $this->visits->workSchedule->work_time
                ]);
}
```

Blade template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    {!! $body !!}
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

Thanks in advance for help!

P.S Using this to send email.

Comment: Are you using markdown for your e-mail?

Comment: Nope. I'm not using markdown

Comment: If anybody faces same problem. Fixed using this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33872239/2414450

Answer (score 2):

It's not rendering because `body` is a variable passed to the view.

You should first render the `body`, then include it into your e-mail.

One solution is to use https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler it will get you started.

The pseudocode for it is:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Pranešimas apie sėkmingą registraciją')
        ->view('email-template')->with(
            [
                'body'                  => renderFromString(EmailTemplate::find(1)->text, 
                [
                    'child_fullname'        => $this->child->name . ' ' . $this->child->surname,
                    'specialist_fullname'   => $this->card->specialist->name,
                    'date_time'             => $this->visits->workSchedule->work_date . ' ' . $this->visits->workSchedule->work_time
            ])
        );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't support Laravel 5.7 version :/. When installing I get an error.
wpb/string-blade-compiler 3.6 requires laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev].

Answer (score 0):

Try `Blade::compileString()`

```
{!! Blade::compileString($body) !!}
```

Comment: Not working. Now shows nothing instead of variables.