# blade variables inside a string that can be compiled in the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my database I have two tables, `Pages` and `Articles`.

In my `Pages` table I have the following:

```
+----+------------------+--------------+
| id |     content      |     slug     |
+----+------------------+--------------+
|  1 | {{$articleBody}} | /news/{slug} |
+----+------------------+--------------+
```

In my `Articles` table I have the following:

```
+----+----------------+--------------+
| id |    content     |     slug     |
+----+----------------+--------------+
|  1 | Blah blah balh | /news/1      |
+----+----------------+--------------+
```

I also have a standard blade file called `wrapper.blade.php`:

```
<body>{{$pageContent}}</body>
```

In my `web.php` file I do the following to return `Page (ID:1)` and `Article`:

```
return view("wrapper", ["Article"=> Article::find(1), "pageContent" => Page::find(1)->content]);
```

The idea is that I can change the `Page` content around `Article` in a CMS manner that includes.

I have tried:

```
   return view("wrapper", ["articleBody"=> Article::find(1)->content, "pageContent" => Blade::compileString(Page::find(1)->content)]);
```

But I haven't had much luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to compile a blade template from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)

Comment: Question updated @Rwd.

Comment: Please can you show how you've implemented this i.e. controller/route code and snippet from your blade file.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You would need to use `eval` but eval wont accept `<?php ?>` generated by `{{ }}`

Comment: Beside, `eval` is not recommended at all for safety reasons

Comment: I have changed the question completely to more like what I'm trying to produce. @Rwd

Comment: Again, refrering to @hadi-aghandeh answer, by anything you will try, your content will remains as string. If you want it to be interpreted. You would need to use `eval` or to rewrite the complete view engine compilation with your own. But since `$bodyContent` must exist at some point when you render your view, why don't your just replace the content has he suggested? `{{ str_replace("{{$articleBody}}", $articleBody,  $content ) }}`

Answer (score 0):

When you use blade , first thing that it does, is to compile the file to something understandable by PHP. For example `{{ => <?php` or `@if(...) @endif => <?php if(...){} ?>`.
when you use `{{first_name}}` in your string the `{{` and `}}` are not there in the file.blade.php when the blade is caching the views. 
after the caching of blade files is done, the server run the php file and `{{first_name}}` will be placed in the file and treated as string.

something that you are looking for is `str_replace()`.

lets say your string is `$String = "Hello something_unique, how are you?"`

then in your blade file use `{{ str_replace("something_unique", $first_name, $String ); }}`. I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey Hadi, this is understandable, however, doesn't  answer my questions.

Comment: @cannor-simpson Hadi explained why you can't and provided you an alternative. Basically, what you would need is to interpret twice your PHP. Once in a file, once in a string. As I suggested in an another comment, you could make use of `eval`, but it's highly risky. I don't know why the answer was downvoted at the first place though.

Answer (score -1):

you should use

```
$string = "Hello".$first_name.", how are you ? "
```