# Flatten includes, make blade faster in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-blade, flatten

Today I work on platform which uses blade as  it's front-end, my task is to make this website faster.

Current initial load is about 3 seconds. What I dicovered is if I remove all includes (there was a lot of nested includes also) initial load drops to 0.8s.

My curent goal for past few days is to keep existing file structure, but make website as it had no includes and i'm failing.

I'm using Laravel 5.5.48 so I decided to use [Te-cho/compile-blades](https://github.com/Te-cho/compile-blades) for blade optimization, but I get such error on project I need to optimize and also on fresh installation of laravel.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for te-cho/compile-blades ^1.0 -> satisfiable by te-cho/compile-blades[v1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - te-cho/compile-blades v1.0 requires illuminate/view 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.
1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.41, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.41].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tought it is incompatibility issue so I tried to install different versions of `Illuminate/View` but also unsuccesfully. Does anyone have an idea how I can make it work?

Comment: That package is outdated and does not support your version of Laravel. Besides, why do you need it? Running php artisan view:cache will compile your views and cache them already. If that is not enough for you, you may extend Blade compiler and use it as per [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)

Comment: there's no such command as `php artisan view:cache` atleast in 5.5, I'll try your suggestion with strings ;)

Comment: Well then you’re out of luck, not sure what else you can do besides changing to a compatible version of Laravel, or taking your chances and doing a fork, within which modifying requirements and praying that it will work.

Comment: though you are right about no such command, it states in that version of Laravel that views are [automatically](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views) compiled into PHP. That command appeared later for manual caching.

Comment: You're right. It does compile to php and that compiled version gives me 3s initial load. I was thinking about flattening php to html. That package I tried using should have done that, sad it's not working for me. Also I just upgraded my version to laravel, 6 hoping to find solution there!

Comment: Have you tried profiling to figure out exactly the file that is loading for that long - JS/CSS/image? It's unlikely that PHP code will be doing it for that long, and if it is then it's a programming mistake that's not going to be avoided simply by caching.

Comment: the project has a lot of issues, one of them is assets also (there's issue with fonts), but it's not major. It will probably be programming mistake, as I said if I remove includes from project and just paste code from them to the section, initial load drops from 3s to 800ms ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  I just suggested product owner to use Vue components instead on includes, bu he thinks that SEO will suffer from it