# How can i pass the variables in the Mail body with laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to pass the variables in my mail body how can I do that.

> I am doing.

I want to send the mail template which is coming from DB, In that template, I have defined the variables to be get replaced when it is sent.

```
`$record = DB::table('email_templates')->select('content','em_temp_id')->where('em_temp_id', 
           $request->select_temp)->where('is_active', 1)->first();
           $body = htmlspecialchars_decode($record->content);' //the html body
```

and my mail function

```
'Mail::send([],[], function($message) use ($Toarray, $ToCCarray, $ToBCCarray, $subject, $body, 
       $is_plainOrHtml){
       $message->to($Toarray, '');
       $message->cc($ToCCarray, '');
       $message->bcc($ToBCCarray, '');
       $message->subject($subject);
       $message->setBody($body, 'text/html'); //for plain text email
 });'
```

Template in DB is like:

```
`<p>Dear {{$userName}},</p>
 <p>The {{$service_provider}}, requesting you to join <strong>{{$channel}}</strong> service. 
 </p>`
```

Array to pass:

```
`$arr_pass['userName'] = 'John';
 $arr_pass['service_provider'] = 'abc.com';
 $arr_pass['channel'] = 'Tom';`
```

How can i pass this array in the mail body?

Comment: Try using the `with` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#via-the-with-method

Comment: This is also going with the email template view, which is i don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Blade::compileString`, which will translate the blade template that you read from the database. There is one tricky part when you do so - how to send the variables' data.

Here are some hints:

1. You could use this library: https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler
2. You could use a `BladeCompiler` similar to [Is there any way to compile a blade template from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)
3. Roll your own compiler by checking the implementation of https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Mail class by extending Mailable class and pass your array to the constructor of the Mail class.
Here in the below example, `RFIRequestMail` is a Mail class created in App\Mail Directory.

**RFIRequestMail.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RFIRequestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $verifierData;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail-view-template');
    }
}
```

**MailController**

```
$sendData = User::find($id);
$data = User::find($company_id);
$sendData["link"] = env("APP_URL");
$sendData["year"] = $request->get("year");
$sendData["user"] = $data->first_name.' '.$data->last_name;
Mail::to($data->email)->send(new RFIRequestMail($sendData));
```

Comment: No, i don't have the view file. As i said my email templates are coming from DB.