# I save blade template with variable in database, how to render the variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I save plain HTML with variable in database, like this

```
<div>
        <span>Nomor: <strong>{{ $pen->nomor_sertifikat ?? "" }}</strong></span>
        <span>
            Nilai: <strong>Rp{{ number_format($pen->nilai_pen,0,',','.')}} 
            </strong>
        </span>
</div>
```

When I call data from database in laravel blade, {!! $data->content !!}, the result is like this

> **Nomor: {{ $pen->nomor_sertifikat }}
> Nilai: Rp{{ number_format($pen->nilai_pen,0,',','.')}}**

The data inside {{ }} can't render. How to solve it?

Comment: Don't save it in the database? Blade won't render a Blade tag inside another Blade tag. {!! !!} just prevents the data inside being run through `htmlspecialchars` first, it doesn't mean that any Blade tags inside it will also be rendered.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string

Answer (score -3):

use

```
 <?= (which you want to input ) ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo  (which you want to input ) ?>
```

but you need to be careful with xss. you can use htmlpurifier