# Laravel: how to create a rendered view from a string instead of a blade file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I've some html with `{{ soimething }}` placeholders in a table.

I would like to get the rendered view from this custom html.
I would like to avoid to manually do string replace.
Is it possible?

Note : I seen suggested questions but I ended finding a more concise way to reach my goal. So I post an answer to this question. Please keep this open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to compile a blade template from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891398/is-there-any-way-to-compile-a-blade-template-from-a-string)

Comment: see this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Blade Facade.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $name='Peter Pan';
        return Blade::render("
        <h1> Hello {$name} </h1>
        ",['name'=>$name]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Found

We can use `\Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::render($string, $data)`

Where

- `$string` is the text to parse, for example
  `Hi {{$username}}`
- `$data` is the same associate array we could normally pass down to `view()` helper, for example `[ 'username' => $this->email ]`

I was missing this from the official doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates

So we can also use

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade`;

`Blade::render($string, $data)`