# I want to output PHP code from Blade in Laravel. In addition, we would like to output the result of the PHP code

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to PHP.

I am currently creating an App in Laravel.
When I write `echo` in the php directive of Blade and pass the php code as a string as an argument, the contents of the php code is output to HTML as it is.
What I want to do is to have the HTML output as the result of the execution of the php code written in the argument of the `echo`.

In a simple way, I can put a judgment in the php directive of Blade and divide it into two branches: one that outputs the contents of the `echo` argument as it is, and another that outputs the result of the execution of the php code.
For example, changing the URL and switching between the above two results is not a problem.
It's a bit of a roundabout way of doing things, but I'm doing it because I need the two results above and I don't want to affect the logic of the one that outputs the contents of the `echo` argument as it is passed.

What I came up with is to prepare a separate App in Laravel, get the HTML output of the contents passed to the `echo` argument in the separate App, execute the PHP code, and return it as HTML.
However, I am not very knowledgeable about infrastructure and have no clue if this is possible or not.

Can you please give me some wisdom?
If I didn't understand your question, please forget it.

Thank you.

[jpg file of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tReT0.jpg)

---

Postscript.

Thank you kind-hearted people.
Indeed `{{ echo '<? php echo date("Y-m-d"); ? >'; }}` also has a way to write it, which I had forgotten. (I also modified the jpg file of the image)
The actual code also has `echo` that spans multiple lines, and I think I wrote this question in confusion.

I was using `{{ echo '<? php echo date("Y-m-d"); ? >'; }}` of the code and I want the output of the result.
I understand that the background behind wanting this is complex and I am talking about something awesomely weird.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is the purpose of this? what problem are you trying to solve by trying to do this?

Comment: You don't need to do echo in Laravel Blade, just do {{ date("Y-m-d") }}

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for the welcome.  
I want the results both before and after running PHP.  
The reason I want before running PHP is to output an html file with Blade's results.  
The reason I want after running PHP is to view the PHP results directly from the browser.  
Thanks for your interest in my strange question.

Comment: @discussion I had forgotten a crucial fact.  
Indeed, `{{}}` eliminates the need for echo.  
Thanks for answering my strange question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for taking the time to answer these strange questions.
I have decided to look at the following as a solution.
I referred to [Laravel: how to create a rendered view from a string instead of a blade file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684314).Thank you.
I don't know if I'm on the right track...

```
// `<? php echo date("Y-m-d"); ? >` get the HTML of as a string and pass it as $html
return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::render($html);
```

If you have any problems with this solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to echo something in the blade go with `{{}}`. It executes the PHP code and outputs the result. no need to wrap the code in PHP directives or echo function.

For example, in your blade:

```php
{{ date("Y-m-d") }}
```

Using PHP directive (@php) is helpful when there are a couple of lines that need to process and you can't place that logic in your controller.

```
@php
  // some multiple PHP codes here
@endphp
```

Please visit the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#blade-directives) page for more.

Comment: I had forgotten a crucial fact.
I remembered that I can use `{{}}` for output.
Thanks for explaining how to use it.

Thanks for answering my strange question.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your code by using **pre** & **code** tag

```
 <pre>
      <code>
        // Here is your code 
     
        $number1 = 5;
        $number2 = 5;
        echo $result = 'result = ' . $number1 + $number2;
    
      </code>
  </pre>
```

And you can output the result like this -

```
@php

  $number1 = 5;
  $number2 = 5;
  echo $result = 'result = ' . $number1 + $number2;

@endphp
```

Output: result = 10

Comment: I see.     
  
The code you wrote seems to output the source code and the result, respectively.  
Am I correct in understanding that if I want each result, the `<pre><code>` outputs the code, and the `@php` outputs the result, separated by an `if' split?  
This time, I want to do this in the same Blade file without using the if branch.  
  
Thanks for answering my odd question.

Answer (score -1):

`{{ date("Y-m-d") }}`

I guess this should work.

Comment: I had forgotten a crucial fact.
I remembered that I can use `{{}}` for output.

Thanks for answering my strange question.

Comment: It's all good. I am totally new to this, just started learning laravel last week. So that was the only thing i could think of, to get the result lol. I guess @Ebi explained it better. I got to learn something new as well.